# How to set a Monorepos project's Next.js public directory on Netlify

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js, netlify

I have a Monorepos project, the frontend project depends on several packages. So in the base directory, there is a `package.json` like below:

```
"workspaces": [
  "apps/*",
  "packages/*",
  "apis/*"
],

"scripts": {
  "dev": "turbo run dev --filter=web...",
  "build": "turbo run build --filter=web...",
}
```

As you can see the `build` command actually builds the `web` sub-project, the `.next` is located in this project. So I set the `Publish directory` to `apps/web/.next` in `Netlify` build settings. The build was successful. But when I open the website, it still says `Page not found`

The fold structure is like this.

```
apps
  web
    .next
    package.json

package.json
```

[image: Deploy log]

So how to set the public directory when I am trying to use a service like Netlify?